# Monitor ASP.NET Session State Variables

Tags: iis, asp.net, performance-monitoring

We are running a number of ASP.NET applications on W2K3 Server and IIS 6.0, and are looking for a way to be able to monitor ASP.NET session state variables (InProc) that are stored in memory.  We are thinking there may be some memory optimization opportunities with some of these session state variables potentially consuming large amounts of RAM.

Is there a way to accomplish this through IIS or Windows rather than instrumenting all of the individual Web apps with code to monitor the session state variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reproduce your sessions that you think use too much memory in a dev environment, then the .Net CLR Profiler and its development web server are a good way to go about this. [Here is a blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/12/11/clr-profiler-and-the-webdev-server.aspx) that outlines the process of setting up the profiler and and pull InProc session data from it.

If you can only pull the data from production, things get harder, but not impossible. See [chapter 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817660.aspx) of the [.Net Framework Production Debugging guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817663.aspx) - it tells you how to pull memory data from running IIS processes that you should be able to analyze.